# CopyFolder or Robocopy?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to copy the PDF files from a mapped remote directory to my local machine using the CopyFolder method. I'm getting a 'permission denied' error, and I believe it may be trying to copy hidden or system files. I'm wanting to preserve the folder structure from the source, and only need the PDFs. Is there a way to do this with CopyFolder, or should I use a shell command like robocopy instead?

Here's my code so far:

```
Public Sub DownloadFiles(FSOFolder As Object)

    Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject
    Set MyFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
    Dim FSOFile As Object
    
    MyFSO.CopyFolder FSOFolder.path & "*", "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Temp"
'code continues
```

The folders are created, but it seems to error when it tries to copy the first file. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: My preference would be robocopy due to the number of flags you can add including multi-threading. Powershell is great too. I take it there are multiple nested folders and you wanted the folders + pdfs within each replicated?

Comment: Correct, that's what I was looking for. I didn't realize how many options robocopy had until I started reading some of the help options.

Answer (score 1):

You could try copying the files individually with error handling to ignore files that you don't have permission to copy. You will need to create the folders manually under this approach.

Here is a sample code to show the concept. I did not test it.

```
Sub CopyFiles()
  Dim FSO as FileSystemObject
  Dim DestinationFolder as Folder
  Dim CopyFolder as Folder

  Set FSO = New FileSystemObject

  Set DestinationFolder = FSO.GetFolder("Your Path to Copy To")
  Set CopyFolder = FSO.GetFolder("Your Path to Copy From")

  Call Recurse(CopyFolder, DestinationFolder)
End Sub

Sub Recurse(CopyFolder as Folder, DesintationFolder as Folder)
  Dim SubFolder as Folder
  Dim File as File

  On Error Resume Next
  For Each File in CopyFolder.Files
    FSO.CopyFile(File.Path, DestinationFolder.Path & "\")
  Next File
  On Error GoTo 0

  For Each SubFolder in CopyFolder.Subfolders
    Call Recurse(SubFolder, FSO.CreateFolder(DestinationFolder.Path & "\" & SubFolder.Name))
  Next SubFolder
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any issues with this.

Comment: I like that method. I also tried this: Shell "cmd /c robocopy " & FSOFolder.path & " " & ThisDocument.path & "\PARTTemp" & " " & "*.pdf" & " /S"  which worked. Which method would you use?

Comment: @Sudio If that method suites your needs then it may be a little cleaner. This method will give you some more freedom to decide what to copy (such as filter types, specific names, etc). I am not very familiar with robo copies but I'd say if your method does what you need then use it!